# What does the ampersand indicate in this bash command 1>&2

Tags: bash, scripting

Quick one, `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout, but what does the ampersand mean? I know if we had `2 > 1` it would output to a file named `1`, what does the ampersand do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It copies file descriptor 1 to file descriptor 2. FD2 is stderr and FD1 is stdout, so it makes any output to stderr go to stdout instead.

Comment: Thanks, so the & means output to file desciptor instead of file

Answer (score 78):

`2>&1` redirects standard error (file handle 2) to the same file that standard output (file handle 1) is **currently** going to.

It's also a position-dependent thing so:

```
prog >x 2>&1 >y
```

will actually send standard error to `x` and standard output to `y` as follows:

- Connect standard output to `x`;
- *Then* connect standard error to same as current standard output, which is `x`;
- *Then* connect standard output to `y`;

Comment: I'd upvote this several times if I could. I've been puzzling this over, and your explanation about the importance of *order* is clearer than the current bash documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections. Thanks!

Comment: This sums things up! In my 8 years of using Linux, no one explained this thing so clearly! Thanks mate.

Comment: Thank you very much, I added it to my flashcards, This answer explain a lot of things at the same time.

Answer (score 28):

The `&` in `&1` duplicates the file descriptor `1`. The duplicated descriptor actually does not behave like a copy, but like an alias of the old one. Duplicating `1` allows multiple streams to be redirected to `1` without overwriting each other.

Example: (no `&`)

```
$ ls existing-file non-existent-file > tmp 2> tmp 
$ cat tmp
existing-file
nt-file: No such file or directory
```

Note that `1` overwrote what `2` wrote. But not when we use `&`:

```
$ ls existing-file non-existent-file > tmp 2>&1 
$ cat tmp
ls: non-existent-file: No such file or directory
existing-file
```

A file descriptor is a handle to a file (or other input/output resource, such as a pipe or network socket). When `1` and `2` are separately redirected to `tmp` (as in the first example), they move their `tmp` file pointer independently. That's why the file descriptors overwrote each other.

According to the [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html):

> [Duplicate file descriptors] refer to the same open file description
>   and thus share file offset and file status flags; for example, if the
>   file offset is modified by using lseek(2) on one of the descriptors,
>   the offset is also changed for the other.

Note that even though `&` acts like an alias, `2>&1` means redirect `2` to the stream that `1` in *currently* pointing to. When `1` is redirected to something else, `2` points to the same file it did independently of `1`.

Observe:

```
$ ls existing-file non-existent-file > tmp 2>&1 > tmp1
$ cat tmp1
existing-file
$ cat tmp
ls: non-existent-file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 20):

The ampersand belongs to the "1", so the snippet really has three parts: "2", ">", "&1". They mean, respectively, "take the data from output stream 2 (which is standard error)", "redirect it", and the redirection target, which is output stream 1. So "&" here allows you to redirect to an existing stream, rather than to a file.

Answer (score 9):

From `info bash`:

```
3.6.7 Duplicating File Descriptors
----------------------------------

The redirection operator
     [N]<&WORD
   is used to duplicate input file descriptors.  If WORD expands to one
or more digits, the file descriptor denoted by N is made to be a copy
of that file descriptor.  If the digits in WORD do not specify a file
descriptor open for input, a redirection error occurs.  If WORD
evaluates to `-', file descriptor N is closed.  If N is not specified,
the standard input (file descriptor 0) is used.

   The operator
     [N]>&WORD
   is used similarly to duplicate output file descriptors.  If N is not
specified, the standard output (file descriptor 1) is used.  If the
digits in WORD do not specify a file descriptor open for output, a
redirection error occurs.  As a special case, if N is omitted, and WORD
does not expand to one or more digits, the standard output and standard
error are redirected as described previously.
```

So `2>&1` duplicates fd 1 onto fd 2.

Answer (score 1):

The *ampersand* doesn't do anything - it's the character in the `2>&1` operator rather than being a thing in its own right.

bash supports several [redirection operators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections), the `2>&1` operator or the `&>` operator tie together the streams of the process before or after redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Before asking what ampersand means, it's best to understand what '>' actually means. Per the bash man page:

> If the first character of the redirection operator is >, the redirection refers to the standard output (file descriptor 1)

eg `>` and `1>` are the same thing so the accepted answer's first example is can also be done without duplicating:

```
prog >y 2>x
```

Figuring out the difference of below also helps:

```
ls -d .. noexists 2>&1 > /dev/null
ls -d .. noexists > /dev/null 2>&1
```

So now it's easier to see ***&*** just tells bash to redirect one file descriptor to another's and you can even undo on the same line and redo it again until tired.